# oracle group by returning more that one row of the same values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

My query is returning the same values using a group by. Can anyone explain this to me why it is like that or what i am doing wrong .

QUERY:

```
SELECT ID, LAST_DAY(EXPDATE) EXPDATE, SUM(BASEUNITS) AS BASEUNITS, SUM(BONUSUNITS) AS BONUSUNITS
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID= '10'
GROUP BY ID, EXPDATE
```

RESULTS :

```
       ID EXPDATE                BASEUNITS  BONUSUNITS  
       10 2016/04/30 12:00:00 AM    8560       0 
       10 2016/04/30 12:00:00 AM    8560       0
```

Comment: Do GROUP BY ID, LAST_DAY(EXPDATE)

Comment: @jarlh wow such a noob mistake thanks alot it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Last_day() function and it is not a aggregate function so in groupby you should specify the function for grouping

```
SELECT ID, 
       LAST_DAY(EXPDATE) EXPDATE, 
       SUM(BASEUNITS) AS BASEUNITS,
       SUM(BONUSUNITS) AS BONUSUNITS
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID= '10'
GROUP BY ID, Last_Day(EXPDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not possible for as Oracle redundancy is not possible with primary key. But as you are getting this you can use distinct before Id

```
SELECT Distinct ID, LAST_DAY(EXPDATE) EXPDATE, SUM(BASEUNITS) AS BASEUNITS, SUM(BONUSUNITS) AS BONUSUNITS
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID= '10'
GROUP BY EXPDATE
```

Comment: Use distinct not group by as you should not group by id because it is primary key

Comment: @Akash tried this but this seems to only return one record and not sum the two together . Previous comment " Do GROUP BY ID, LAST_DAY(EXPDATE)" Worked perfectly Thanks btw .

Comment: okay :) then use that way, but primary key should not be grouped together

Comment: ID is part of multiple primary keys ex:   PRIMARY KEY: SYS_C001161522 (ORGID, PRODUCTID, ID, ACTSEQ, EXPDATE)

Comment: @AndreiMaieras, depends on if all GROUP BY columns are selected or not. E.g. select col1 from ... group by col1, col2 may return duplicate col1 values.